# How can you prevent running a resolver based on the selection set?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

Example:

```
query {
  me {
    starredPosts {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

How can the server notice that only the ids are requested, and use the already-fetched `user.starredPosts` (an array of ids), instead of calling `Posts.findOne(id)` for each id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can examine `info.fieldNodes[0].selectionSet.selections` or use `graphql-fields` package:

```
const postsIds = user.starredPosts

const selectionSet = Object.keys(graphqlFields(info))

const onlySelectingId = isEqual(['__typename', 'id'], selectionSet.sort())
if (onlySelectingId) {
  return postIds.map(id => ({ id, __typename: 'Post' }))
} else {
  return favs.map(id => Post.findOneById(id))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem and are in the process of open-sourcing the tools we've built out over the last year and a half internally to address these issues: https://github.com/4Catalyzer/graphql-node-resource/pull/1.

The solution we use is, for object resolvers like that, to resolve them to a "stub" object that contains only the ID, something like:

```js
const childField = {
  type: ChildType,
  resolve: obj => ({ id: obj.childId }),
};
```

Then we use `DataLoader` to fetch the additional fields on the child objects when they're required by using our own default resolver.

We connect to our internal REST API, which supports batching on those requests, so queries that require additional fields get efficiently dispatched and resolved.

However, this does introduce potential for error when writing custom resolvers, as there's no guarantee that `obj` actually has the relevant fields. We've addressed this by setting up our static types to prevent unchecked access to properties of `obj`.